# How to set instant message using jquery?

Tags: c#, jquery

When we register some sites with our name it shows some message like "Name already taken please try another one" if the same name exists. I am planning to create a sign up form in c# with jquery I also want show this same message if user name already exist in database. How it is possible? I am new in jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you'd have to send an ajax request (while the user is typing his/her name) to a controller method, pass that name in that request and check if the name exists in your database and then populate the message as "Name already taken" or "valid Name" on the basis of response you send from the controller to the calling ajax method.

Comment: yes there you are. Can you show me a simple example with one text box. Because am new in jquery

Comment: @Signetsoftwaretrainee - Im afraid thats not how StackOverflow works. There are hundreds of examples for this kind of functionality out there. What you need to do is try it, and when you have a *specific* problem then come and ask that question.

Comment: why would someone downvote my response, I've just explained what to briefly, I don't think I need to write down the exact code with examples unless they are stuck at some point

Comment: @Jamiec, I am sorry i will delete  this question. sorry for the inconvinence

Comment: @Signetsoftwaretrainee - No inconvenience, just trying to help ;)

Comment: I downvoted this answer because I don't think it will help @Signetsoftwaretrainee solve their problem.

Comment: @Subash, am sorry subash because of me you got downvote.

Comment: @Richard Everett, Excuse me sir, Subash was correct what I mean actually.

Comment: Apologies, I stand corrected. SO won't let me remove my downvote unless the answer is edited.

Comment: @Richard Everett, I got blocked :)

Comment: @RichardEverett I edited my answer, would you remove your downvote now ?